# Generalizing pullbacks

Tags: category-theory, terminology, limits-colimits

A cospan is two morphisms having the same codomain. A pullback is a limit of a cospan. If instead of having two morphisms, we have a set of morphisms having the same codomain, is there a name corresponding to "cospan" and a name corresponding to "pullback" (as we have with "discrete diagram" and "Cartesian product")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are commonly called [wide pullbacks](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/wide+pullback). As far as I can tell, this terminology is due to Definition 1.2.3 of Taylor's 
[Quantitative domains, groupoids and linear logic](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/bfb0018351). The term *wide cospan* for the analogous diagram is in use, but appears to be slightly less common.